# Using function output for instance initialisation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do this:

```
class Color:
    def __init__(self, r, g, b):
        self.r = r
        self.g = g
        self.b = b

im_rgb = Image.open('in.png').convert('RGB')
color = Color(im_rgb.getpixel((0, 0)))
```

.getpixel() returns three values, but python interpreter only sees one:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'g' and 'b'
```

Why? Is what I'm trying to do way too cheeky?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get one return value which is a tuple of three elements. Use the * to unpack them:

```
color = Color(*im_rgb.getpixel((0, 0)))
```